# #OpsHub - OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. Cannot move folder to temporary renamed folder having same name. Move failed

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trying to migrate my local TFS using opsHub, unfortunately I am getting a error: **OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. Cannot move folder to temporary renamed folder having same name. Move failed!**

And I cannot find a way to skip that change set and keep going...

Any idea?

Comment: Hi, Try clearing out all the contents of the O:\ drive after closing the utility. And then do a retry from the UI.

Comment: Hi @OpshubInc., unfortunatelly didn´t work. Error still happening... I closed the utility, deleted all files of the o:\ drive, opened the UI and retry the same migration. Any idea?

Comment: Hi, could you please send us the logs from "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs" at support@opshub.com

Comment: Hi @OpshubInc. sent you an email with log files

Comment: @OpshubInc. - Any ideai? Hope you can help me with that! tks.